# Ember - get state of multiple checkboxes one by one

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, checkbox

I am working on an Ember app (version 1.11, old one) and have multiple checkboxes build over in loop, code as below. 
I need to know if an element has been checked or unchecked in action.

**Ember ehbs**:

```
{{#each item in data}}
 <label>
 <input type="checkbox" checked="isChecked" {{action "getData" item on="change"}}/>
 <span>{{item.type}}</span>
 </label>
{{/each}}
```

**Ember Component**:

```
var component = Ember.Component.extend({
 isChecked: true,
 actions: {
  getData: function(data){
   var state = this.get('isChecked');
   var type = data.type;
  }
 }
})
```

I thought the variable's "isChecked" value will be maintained for each individual checkbox, but its not the case, it is just one variable for all checkboxes.
So, how can I achieve this OR check individual states for all checkboxes whether its checked or unchecked.

In long run, I am trying to get here - [http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qaruviwuze/edit?html,js](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qaruviwuze/edit?html,js,output),output but dont want to access and play with DOM as its done here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make each checkbox as component

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="isChecked" {{action "getData" item on="change"}}/>
```

as follows checkbox-component

```
{{#each model as |item|}}
  {{checkbox-component isChecked=item.isCheked}}
{{/each}}
```

such that you can retrieve easily each check item value.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: "input",
  isChecked: false,
  attributeBindings: ['type', 'checked'],
  type: 'checkbox',

  checked: function() {
    return this.get('isChecked');
  }.property('isChecked'),

  click: function() {
    console.log(this.set('checked', this.$().prop('checked')))
  }
});
```

check https://ember-twiddle.com/996f6408266af8cd4d3372bed8e8331c?openFiles=components.checkbox-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.checkbox-component.hbs

Comment: Thanks, I will try this thing tomorrow and let you know if this fits in.

Comment: Hey, how do I send an action from this click of checkbox to the parent of its parent, as I have to pass the data like check state and item type.

Comment: you can do this.get('targetObject').send('actionName', params);

Comment: this.get('targetObject') will be point to the resepective controller, else if ur in a view , you can use this.get('parentView')

Comment: Well, the targetObject should be the controller name, right. I tried that but its not working. I have only one controller and nested components in this case. And no view, am just working out of components.

Comment: Actually, I just realized, that from this click, I need to send action to controller only. So, would calling this.sendAction('actionName',filterFn) from click would work, assuming I have 'actionName' defined in controller?

Comment: No, its not. Any idea, whats going wrong. Need to call a action "X" (defined in controller) from nested component (checkbox) and pass params.

Comment: https://ember-twiddle.com/996f6408266af8cd4d3372bed8e8331c?openFiles=components.checkbox-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.checkbox-component.hbs check here  to call controller action

Comment: Yeah, so my checkbox component is 3 levels deep nested. In the link you have shared, it is direct descendant, not nested, right.

Comment: Hey, got it done, i had to basically bubble up the action to the controller , like as given in link - http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/sendaction-on-stack-components-controller-actions/3332/2 . So, this worked. Thanks anyway, for your help. :-)

Comment: thats gr8, thanks for sharing the other approach too.